# Affine map without fixed points is injective

Tags: affine-geometry, fixed-points

My question is: given an affine endomorph map $f$ in such way that there no exists fixed points (that is, $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x$). Then, can we assert that $f$ is injective?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know, I'm looking for a hint